# Selecting the most recent entry subject to a condition

Tags: sql

I have a table with a 'date' field (written in an integer form), and a 'grocery_item' field. The date specifies when a certain grocery item was ordered

I am trying to write a query that slelect the most recent entry for every grocery items that occured before a given date:

ex:

```
id  | date    |  grocery_item
1   | 201101  |  a
2   | 201101  |  b
3   | 201102  |  a
4   | 201103  |  b
5   | 201104  |  c
```

get most recent that occured before 201103

```
id  | date    |  grocery_item
2   | 201101  |  b
3   | 201102  |  a
```

Any help will be more than appreciated!! -- I am blanking out on this ...

Comment: Why on earth are the dates stored as integers?

Comment: It's just an assignment I have... I guess it's the concept that counts... Complaints? bring it up with my prof haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, MAX(date) AS date, grocery_item
FROM table
WHERE date < 201103
GROUP BY grocery_item
```